# Edit html code from UIWebView swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I am presenting a WebView in my app, however, there are some modifications I would like to make on the website I am presenting. If I load google.com, for example, I might want to change the text of the "google search" button. How do I go about doing this?

The similar questions asked are all in Objective C and do not seem to be working.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help for you. In Swift3

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
var firstLoad = true
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.webView.delegate = self
    self.webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com.pk/")!))
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    let evaluate: String = "document.getElementById('main-title').value='\("New title")';"
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: evaluate)

    //or
    if firstLoad {
        firstLoad = false
        let html: String? = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.documentElement.outerHTML")
        //Edit html here, by parsing or similar.
        webView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: Bundle.main.resourceURL)

        //print HTML for testing
        print("HTML \(html!)")
    }

}
```

Comment: It can get annoying but using `UIWebView`'s `stringByEvalutingJavascript()` will give you the control you are looking for.  You will just have to write javascript to change the content you are targeting.